# Как сделать два сайдбара фиксированной ширины в Twitter bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap, css

Добрый день, ситуация такая что сайт сверстан на `twitter boostrap`.
Имеет левый сайдбар, основное тело страницы, правый сайдбар.
Все в резиновой верстке (`container-fluid`).
Необходимо, чтобы два сайдбара имели строго определенные размеры в `250px`, основное тело страницы растягивается по длине страницы.
Получается:

- левый фиксированный по ширине `250 px`
- растягивающее тело контента
- правый фиксированный по ширине `250px`

При минимальной ширине `@media` (`min-width: 767px`), сайдбары переходят в основное тело страницы.

Пока идей маловато, строго определить размер `width: 250px` в сайдбарах, и верстка плывет.

Разделение по сайдбарам:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <?php echo View::factory('/templates/include/error'); ?>
        <?php echo View::factory('/templates/include/message'); ?>

        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 left-sidebar">
                    <?php echo $left_sidebar; ?>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 content">
                    <?php echo $content ?>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 right-sidebar">
                    <?php echo $right_sidebar; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Надеюсь на вашу помощь )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Посмотреть пример](https://jsfiddle.net/vqdL3wv4/2/)**.

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="left-sidebar">Левый</div>
            <div class="content">Центральный</div>
            <div class="right-sidebar">Правый</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS (для новых браузеров)

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .wrapper {
        overflow: auto;
    }
    .left-sidebar,
    .content,
    .right-sidebar {
        float: left;
    }    
    .left-sidebar,
    .right-sidebar{
        width: 250px;
    }
    .content {
        width: calc(100% - 250px * 2);
    }
}
```

CSS (для старых браузеров)

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .wrapper {
        display: table;
        table-layout: fixed;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .left-sidebar,
    .content,
    .right-sidebar {
        display: table-cell;
    }
    .left-sidebar,
    .right-sidebar {
        width: 250px;
    }
}
```

Comment: отлично, то что нужно. Большее вам спасибо, я бы век мучался

Answer (score 0):

Благодарю пользователя VenZell.
На основе решения данной проблемы решил противоположный вариант:
Поле контента должно быть фиксировано, а отступы слева\справа должны изменяться в зависимости от разрешения экрана.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="indent"></div>
        <div class="content">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            LOGO
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 text-right">
            Support info
          </div>
        </div>
      <div class="indent"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS (для новых браузеров)

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .wrapper{
        overflow: auto;
    }
    .indent,
    .content{
        float: left;
    }    
    .content{
        width: 640px;
    }
    .indent {
        width: calc((100% - 640px)/2);
        min-height: 1px;
    }
  }
```

CSS (для старых браузеров)

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .wrapper {
        display: table;
        table-layout: fixed;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .indent,
    .content{
        display: table-cell;
    }
    .content{
        width: 640px;
    }
}
```

Надеюсь, что это кому-нибудь пригодится.